# Categories and Subcategories MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, categories

I have a big problem, at least for me.
I have a Table with categories and unlimited subcategories.
The table looks like this:

**ID Parent_ID Name**

1   null     riding

2   1        gallopa

3   null     figure

4   2        trapper

And there is a table containing items wich are attributed to a category.
The table looks like this:

**ID cattegory_ID Name**

1    4             fast

2    1             slow

3    3             high

4    2             low

Now I want to retrieve them from the database and show them in my mvc2 application like this:
A Fieldset for the first category, and one for the subcategory in the fieldset before. The items should be listed in the fieldset with checkboxes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyMWD.png

I like to work with `@Html.CheckBoxfor`.

Has any one got any idea? I'm working on this problem since last week without a result.
I tried to solve the problem recursively but it did not work.
An example would be beautiful, thanks a lot!

**Thanks a lot for your answer!
Everything works fine! But how to do a Httppost with this model? And  how to get the Status Checked or not Checked of every checkbox?**

here is my start:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewHorse(NewHorseModel collection)
    {
      collection.Cattegories.Count(); <------------is always null! Why?
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a PartialView that has the Category-class as a Model, something like this:

**Category.cshtml**

```
@model Category

<fieldset>
    <legend>@Model.Name</legend>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Choices)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("Choice", item);
    }

    @foreach(var item in Model.Subcategories)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("Category", item);
    }
</fieldset>
```

**Choice.cshtml**

```
@model StackOverflow_Tester.Models.Choice

<p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Selected) @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected)</p>
```

in your main view, you'd simply render the partialview based on the categories:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("Category", item);
}
```

Now you need to pass only the root categories into your view

This should give you a recursive view with categories and/or subcategories.

**UPDATE**

The viewmodel/model could look like this:

**Category.cs**

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
    public List<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
}
```

**Choice.cs**

```
public class Choice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

*I've updated the code in the top as well, to reflect this Model*

Hope this helps!

Comment: and how to create the checkboxfor? (the model including the items)

Comment: But how to get the IDs of the checked checkboxen when i do a post? sth. like this i think:   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult testview(FormCollection collection) ???

Comment: I think you should post this as a separate question to increase the posibility of good answers. I'd suggest you create a question where you post the HTML-source of your page (run the app, do a view source, and copy the code that is rendered as the form)